# Insert CSS in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I know that it's possible to add CSS to a page with Content_Scripts, but I want to use the InsertCSS function in a JS file.

I have:

```
chrome.tabs.insertCSS(null, {code: "adfree.css"});
```

But it doesn't change anything of a webpage. I gave the permissions:

```
"permissions": [
    "tabs", "*://*"
],
```

Why doesn't it work?

**Edit:**

```
chrome.tabs.insertCSS({file: "adfree.css"});
```

or

```
chrome.tabs.insertCSS(null, {file: "adfree.css"});
```

doesn't work also...

Comment: I have the same problem. Maybe something wrong with file path.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing it a file name, but using the `code` key, when you should be using the `file` key:

```
chrome.tabs.insertCSS(null, {file: "adfree.css"});
```

See [the documentation](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-insertCSS) for more info.

Comment: Tryed that and also chrome.tabs.insertCSS({file: "adfree.css"});, but doesn't work